# Emacs 28.2 does not open from finder/dock on OS X Monterey

Tags: osx, start-up

I downloaded Emacs 28.2 (released 2022-09-12) for OS X from [here](https://emacsformacos.com/).  When I try to open it from Spotlight search or the dock, it sometimes bounces, sometimes hangs, but never opens.

I can open it from the command-line, and it says:

```
$ emacs
2023-02-02 09:12:34.193 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[3831:29426] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
2023-02-02 09:12:34.450 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[3831:29426] It's not legal to call -layoutSubtreeIfNeeded on a view which is already being laid out.  If you are implementing the view's -layout method, you can call -[super layout] instead. Break on void _NSDetectedLayoutRecursion(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
```

How do I get it opening from the dock?

I'm on Monterey (12.6.3) on an Intel MacBook Pro.

**EDIT**: I tried 28.1-4, which also did not work.  I tried 27.2-3, which does work (after going through a warning about how apple cannot scan it for malicious software).  I guess I'll stick to 27.2-3.

Comment: you can ignore those error msgs. they're aimed at developers. they do make me wonder if your `emacs` is pointing to the one you expect. confirm with `ls -l $(which emacs)`.

Comment: does it not open from the "recents" section of the dock?

Comment: fwiw, 28.2 from https://emacsformacos.com installed as `/Applications/Emacs.app` #worksforme on Ventura (aarch64) and Big Sur(x86_64). via `emacs` symlinks, `open -a Emacs`, Finder, "recents" section of the Dock, d-n-d from Finder to Dock and launch...

Comment: @nega It does not open from any part of the dock (pinned or recent). Just bounces. Yes, I figure I can ignore the messages, just thought I'd add them.

Comment: @nega Sadly, I cannot test anymore, because I am sticking with 27.2-3, which works.